Blender Pythopn API - Import OBJ files

Hello,
When I want to import an obj file with Blender Python, it adds with the Legacy import method. I want to do it with the obj import above. How do we do this? When I add with Legacy, the quality decreases.

Have you tried right-clicking the item and then Copy Python Command? You will get bpy.ops.wm.obj_import()
